# Type-safe map of objects with corresponding names

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a generic type with the `name` property:

```js
type Attribute<Name, Value> = {
    name : Name
    value : Value
}
```

The important parts here are that:

1. The `name` parameter will be used as an exact string literal for the attribute's name.
   For instance, `Attribute<"width", number>` instead of `Attribute<string, number>`.
2. The real scenario the `Attribute` type will have much more properties, but for simplicity it has only `value`.

Now I want to have a map (object, dictionary, `{}`) which can map `Attribute["name"]` to the corresponding `Attribute`.
To put it simple, the map `m` of types `Attribute<"width", number>` and `Attribute<"height", number>` should return `Attribute<"width", number>` on accessing `m.width` and `Attribute<"height", number>` on `m.height`.

Like this:

```js
function f(m : AttributesMap<[
    Attribute<"width", number>,
    Attribute<"height", number>,
]>) {
    m.width.name // "width" type
    m.height.name // "height" type
}
```

To achieve this I tried the following approach:

```js
type AttributesMap<
    Attribute_ extends Attribute<string, any>[]
> = {
    [key in Attribute_[number][`name`]] : Attribute_[number]
}
```

But it returns `Attribute<"width", number> | Attribute<"height", number>` on accessing both `m.width` and `m.height`.

I understand that it does so because of the `[number]` property at the left is totally independent of the same `[number]` on the right.
But I cannot figure out how to make it work properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a union because in the values you are accessing every value by using *indexed access*:

```
Attribute_[number]
```

Instead of this, let's map through `Attribute_[number]`. Then we can map through the union using [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and change the key to `name` property by using the [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as):

```
type AttributesMap<Attribute_ extends Attribute<string, any>[]> = {
  [K in Attribute_[number] as K['name']]: K;
};
```

Testing:

```
function f(
  m: AttributesMap<[Attribute<'width', number>, Attribute<'height', number>]>,
) {
  m.width.name; // "width" type
  m.height.name; // "height" type
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAgswCcCWAjArsCAeAcgQwFsIAaKANTwBs0IA+KAXigG8BYAKCigDtCIAuKPiIBuDlwBuVGoIrUIY9gF9FHAGZpuAY2BIA9tyhqAFOKgFBcRKgwQAzgFk8YLAG0rydJiwByAO5IACbAABY+pNxoBCgQCLSkHjbePiEQSADmIcDhPFExcQC68RwAlCxmBAB0AcEhlbyiUAD0TVAARDWhbVCgkBWVqRlZ9Xwiza1tg5nA3b0QHEocHHOw8J62js5YiV4QAPpQEAAemNyBdqvWu1h21tzppHjcILSuRYzlnFCuANJQSIYdrY9q5ItFYgUoHgLj9XD4GhAfAUCoIfooVBwgA)

Comment: Thanks!
Do we really need this additional `Values`?
I tried `K in Attribute_[number] as K["name"]` and it worked.

Comment: yes, you are right. will update the answer